# Sum of a= ord(A) and of b= ord(B) defined as ord ( {A, B} ) . Trying to understand 2 examples given by Lipschutz, Theory and Problems Of Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I'm reading a somewhat old fashionned book on Set Theory ( first edition 1964).

I think I have understood the concept of ordinal number : if A is well ordered, then the order type of A ( its equivalence class under the relation of similarity) is A's cardinal number.

I'm now trying to understand operations on ordinals, and firstly, *addition*.

My author says that: if A and B are disjoint and if a= ord(A) and b=ord(B), then

```
              a+b = ord ( {A,B} ).
```

With some aid from another book, namely Pinter's *Book of Set Theory*  ( and from answers on this site), I understood that

{A,B} is, so to say, the *ordered union* of A and of B under the relation R such that  xRy  ( or : (x,y) belongs to R if you prefer) :

(1) x and y belong to A and x precedes ( or is equal to) y

(2) x and y belong to B and x precedes ( or is equal to) y

(3) x belongs to A and y belongs to B.

At this point my author gives an example aiming at illustrating addition of ordinals ( **please, see image below**).

My question : **why does he say that in one case " *n+omega = omega*" and that , in the other case " *omega + n is greater that omega***".

Remark : my question is not on non-commutativity of ordinal addition; I am perfectly ready to accept this fact; what I do not understand is the *reason why the "results" are not the same in the two cases*

Remark : the author uses the symbols P and " omega" defined as follows :

**P** :  the set of counting numbers

"omega" : ordinal number of P ( the set of counting numbers)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that if $A$ is well ordered then the order type of $A$ is its cardinal number.  The well ordered set $\{1,2,3,4,5,\ldots,z\}$ has order type $\omega+1$, but its cardinal is $\aleph_0$ (or $\omega$ if we use it as a cardinal).  It is an example of the addition you are talking about.  We started with $\omega$ and put one element after it.  If we put the new element before it we would have $\{z,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$ which has the same order type as $\omega$.  This is $1+\omega$ because we put the single element first, and shows and example of $1+\omega=\omega$

Comment: @RossMillikan.Thanks. May I ask you how is defined  the difference between " order type" and "ordinal number" of a well ordered set?

Comment: I see them as the same.

Comment: @RossMillikan.This is the way I had understood the first sentence of your answer.

Comment: The first sentence says the order type is not the *cardinal* number.  For the ordinal $\omega+1$ the cardinal is just $\aleph_0$.  There are many countable ordinals.  They all have the same cardinal.

Comment: @RossMillikan.Ok, my mistake.